# PHP regex solution - Remove some special characters and replace some with text

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP variable, say

```
$myvariable = "te    xt!@ na#@)(me+=&t^*ext?>;.'na^%me";
```

I want to replace special characters and **group of special characters** including blank space with a **single** underscore `_`. The string may contain `&` and it may be replaced with `and`.

The result of previous variable should be;

```
te_xt_na_me_andt_ext_na_me
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes, *anything* but "characters" is regarded disposable.

```
$patterns = array(
    '/&/'             => 'and',  // Ampersand to "and"
    '/[^[:alpha:]]+/' => '_'     // Anything *but* a character to underscore
);

$result = preg_replace(array_keys($patterns), array_values($patterns), $input);
```

The last pattern replaces groups of one or more occurences of "non-word" characters according to the current locale<sup>1</sup> (and thus including white-space).

---

<sup>1</sup> Side-note (might be irrelevant): if the server the script runs on has `en_US` as locale, the following replacements occur:

```
$input = 'app!le___s &!   orän=%ges';
$result = 'app_le_s_and_or_n_ges';
```

If the locale is `de_DE`, this would be the result:

```
$result = 'app_le_s_and_orän_ges';
```

Because `ä` is part of `[[:alpha:]]` in this particular locale. The obvious solution to circumvent this would be to substitute the character class for `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: That was useful.. Can you tell me how to keep the last dot "." in the string, if there is, suppose like a filename with extension..

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
$myvariable = str_replace('&','and',$myvariable)
$myvariable = preg_replace ('/[^a-z]+/i', '_' , $myvariable)
```

see: http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

the caret (^) inside the squared brackets means to look for everything, that is not declared in the brackets. So every special character is not "a-z". The plus signalises, that multiple occurences should be matched. The 'i' behind the delimiting slash means to do a case-insensitive search.